# Are there any programs that i can use to test my website against hacks?

Tags: security, testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools to check for common vulnerabilities?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/244/tools-to-check-for-common-vulnerabilities)

Are there any applications out there that can run random queries against my website and try and find holes in it? My particular concern is sql injections?

Answer (score 1):

Some assembly... i mean research and learning required, but [metasploit](http://metasploit.com/) is a good bet. [sqlninja](http://sqlninja.sourceforge.net/) is also worth taking a look at, if you're specifically worried about sql injections

Answer (score 1):

use **[Havij](http://itsecteam.com/en/projects/project1_page2.htm)** for checking for sql injection vulnerabilities.

**[Acunetix Web Vulnerability Scanner](http://www.acunetix.com/)** for all other scans.