# Webiste Testing for SQL and CSS injection

Tags: php, mysql, html, css

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Tools to check for common vulnerabilities?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/244/tools-to-check-for-common-vulnerabilities)

I would like to ask some tools or code for testing my new created website from ***SQL or CSS*** injection. The website in created in PHP and has login module which is use for ticketing system for support module.

Url convention is **www.domainname.com/index.php**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: CSS injection ?

Comment: yes. try google it..

Comment: Twitter had a serious CSS injection vulnerability once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tool I have been using for SQL Injection / XSS checks is Acunetix... It can even help point you in the right direction for fixing any security issues. You can get the free edition here:

http://www.acunetix.com/cross-site-scripting/scanner-download.htm